# NeweyWest applied to many regressions

Tags: r

Sorry for the basic question. I am running many different regressions and am correcting the standard errors using the NeweyWest procedure. My question is, rather than running the NeweyWest adjustment for each regression, can I just run it over all of them in one step.

For example: I have the following regressions

```
Reg1, Reg2, Reg3 etc
```

I tried the following but didn't have any success.

```
 Reg_List = c("Reg1", "Reg2", "Reg3")
 coeftest(Reg_list, vcov=NeweyWest(Reg_list, lag = lag_length - 1, prewhite = FALSE, adjust = TRUE, sandwich = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get the values of 'Reg_List'.  in a `list` with `mget` and then use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and apply the `NeweyWest` function

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
lapply(mget(Reg_List), 
   function(x) coeftest(x, vcov = NeweyWest(x, lag = lag_length -1,  
       prewhite = FALSE, adjust = TRUE, sandwich = TRUE)))
#$Reg1

#t test of coefficients:

#              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) -12.533601  22.665383 -0.5530    0.5879    
#RealGNP       0.169136   0.020678  8.1793 4.154e-07 ***
#RealInt      -1.001438   3.664142 -0.2733    0.7881    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


#$Reg2
# ..
```

Here, we assume `lag_length` is already an objected created in the OP's environment

---

Using a reproducible example

```
library(sandwich)
data(Investment)
Reg1 <- lm(RealInv ~ RealGNP + RealInt, data = Investment)
Reg2 <- Reg1
Reg3 <- Reg1
lag_length <- 4
Reg_List = c("Reg1", "Reg2", "Reg3")
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun